# How to click on a button with href attribute on webpage

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have used the below code to click on login button but it is not working:

Trial 1:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='https://www.luxproflashlights.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubHV4cHJvZmxhc2hsaWdodHMuY29tLw%2C%2C/']")).click();
```

Trial 2:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log In")).click();
```

Comment: probably should be "//a[href='...']  or "//a[contains(@href, 'login')]"   text() is for the contents between <a href = '...'> and </a>.

Answer (score 1):

If the element contains both the *href* attribute and the *text* **Log In** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `partialLinkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Log In"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'luxproflashlights') and contains(., 'Log In')]"))).click();
  ```